# get exif from image data downloaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jpeg, exif

When I get an image via `ajax` from `Amazon s3` I get the image data back. How do I get the `exif` data from the image data? I can see `Exif` in the data I just can't get it out. I would like to access it via `javascript`

[image]

The data appears like following.

```
"����JFIFHH���ExifMM*    z
���(1�2��i�AppleiPhone 6sHH9.2.12016:03:05 18:55:36������"�'@��"�
6�>�
F�
N��   �
V�|^��289��289��
��������2j�3��4$�2016:03:05 18:55:362016:03:05 18:55:36�V/
� C5Apple iOSMM
 h�  
 
 
�   bplist00�UflagsUvalueYtimescaleUepoch���J�;��'-/8= ?����;�����y����55AppleiPhone 6s front camera 2.65mm f/2.2��

http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.4.0"> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/" xmp:CreateDate="2016-03-05T18:55:36" xmp:ModifyDate="2016-03-05T18:55:36" xmp:CreatorTool="9.2.1" photoshop:DateCreated="2016-03-05T18:55:36"/> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <?xpacket end="w"?>��8Photoshop 3.08BIM8BIM%��ُ���    ���B~���
"��   
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������    
���w!1AQaq"2�B����   #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������C
```

Comment: It seems you're doing something wrong. Can you tell what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get exif data from an image URL

Comment: Why do you need it on js?

Answer (score 0):

if you get image from ajax. get its base64 and you can get exif data like this:

```
var b64 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABA......";
var bin = atob(b64.split(',')[1]);
var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(bin));
alert(exif.Orientation);
```

Comment: how do I get the base64 from the data returned from the ajax?